# What is return type of AVG function in JPQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using AVG function in JPQL named query. But I am getting error **Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class**
I have tried taking it in Integer, Float, BigDecimal variable but still it didn't work.

I am calculating Average of bigDecimal values. Even I tried as `AVG(CAST(s.marks AS FLOAT))`

Can anybody please help?

Comment: When asking about an exception cause by some code executing a query over an entity mapped to a table, post the code, post the exception stack trace, post the entity, and post the definition of the table.

Comment: Cause of exception because of type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally done. It returns as Double